# I am unable to use EasyBlogger Python script with PyPandoc

Tags: python, oauth, blogger, blogspot

Formerly I used googlecl, but it doesn1t work anymore due to authentication issues, google dropped OAuth1 support, or something. Then I tried EasyBlogger script to post blogposts from command line, but it proved very tricky: http://blog.rraghur.in/p/blog-page.html

I simply followed the steps on that page. First I had to install a package called Pandoc. It took about 3 weeks for me to finding out how to install it. Finally I managed to install it as a package pandoc-static for my Arch Linux box. Unfortunately easyblogger script still doesn't work, however I also installed a package called pypandoc from github:

When I run it with python2, I get error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easyblogger", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3074, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3060, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3087, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 645, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 946, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 833, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pypandoc' distribution was not found and is required by EasyBlogger
```

When I run it with python3, I get different error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easyblogger", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('EasyBlogger==0.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'easyblogger')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/EasyBlogger-0.9.0-py3.4.egg/blogger/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'EasyBlogger'
```

I really need some blogger script, because all of my blogs are out of order now for about 2 months.

Comment: Any luck with this? Note that pypandoc has received some serious upgrades.

Comment: I tried again, same result: http://pastebin.com/x5aBWirD

Comment: Are you sure EasyBlogger has been installed correctly? Perhaps you could ask the [author](http://blog.rraghur.in/p/blog-page.html) for more information.